# Cake PHP pass parameter with form to controller

Tags: forms, cakephp, parameters

I don´t know how to securely pass a parameter via form with Cake.
The method I use now is as follows:

```
$this->Form->create('Post', array('label' => '', 'action' => '', 'url' => 'inseratAngenommen/'.$postId));
```

In the controller there stands:

```
function inseratAngenommen($id = null, $bs = null){
    //stuff
}
```

The poblem is that the user can modify the output number of $postId in the browser:

```
action="/cakephp/posts/inseratAngenommen/149"
```

For that case I want to pass the parameter invisible in the HTML. Is that possible?
I thought of a method like the Form->PostLink provides. I couldn´t find anything.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the security component. this way form tempering is not possible.

Comment: That sounds like the real way to go, thank you :)

Comment: I'm not sure the security-component protects agains changing the *value* of a form-input. Afaik it only protects agains adding/removing inputs. So if you're going to use it, please check carefully if it does what you want. It *may* validate the form-action, I'll have to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not** possible to send an parameter securely over a website as the data is sent by the user.

Use the validation methods of cakephp to make sure the data is correct.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. The validation rules are fired normally but when the user changes a field with e.g. firebug from e.g. "149" to "148" the validation array can´t distinguish that from a normal input and passes it to the controller. I´ll try ptica´s method 2 as that sounds quite safe ...

Answer (score 0):

1] method one: add obscurity: hide the $id into a posted field by:

```
$this->Form->hidden('id');
$this->Form-field('id');  // even this one will do as cake hides ids by default
```

2] method two: keep the id on the server for instance in a session

```
$this->Session->write('current-edited-post-id', $id); // upon form display
$id = $this->Session->read('current-edited-post-id'); // upon form submission
```

but be warned thou, that method 2 doesn't behave well, if the user opens multiple tabs and operates one session from both of them :(

Comment: Thanks for sharing that knowledge. In the first place I tried it with hidden form fields but they are on show just like the url-param-thing. Method 2 sounds more secure but I got a strange problem with very slowly changing sessions. When fixed I´ll try that. Thanks

Comment: Dont use any such session stuff - it will haunt you as user as soon as you use more than a single tab (which basically everyone does).

Comment: Karl, 've you removed the $postId you've got in the form creation?
ie.  `$this->Form->create('Post');`

Comment: yeah, using tabs will screw it, stick to method 1